# Sql ошибка 5123

Tags: sql-server, sql

привет. отсоединенная база данных при попытке присоединения обратно выдает ошибку 5123
подскажите,в чем проблема и как ее устранить

Answer (score 1):

Не пробовали - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/b253aae4-b511-4823-b0ac-a27b20345acd/sql-error-5123?forum=fordataru